# Sockets and Timeout Errors

Tags: vb.net, sockets

I'm building a program that has a very basic premise.

For X amount of Objects
Open Conection
Perform Actions
Close Connection
Open Next

Each of these connections is made on a socks5 proxy and after about the 200th connection I get "The operation has timeout" errors. I have tested all the proxies and they work just fine and the really wierd thing is if I shut down the program and restart it again the problems go away. So I'm left to believe that when I'm closing my connection that its really not closing the connection and the computer is being overloaded. How cna i force all socks connections to close that are associated with a class?

```
            socket.Shutdown(SocketShutdown.Both);
            //socket.Close();

            socket.Disconnect(true);
            socket = null;
```

In reponse to a tip to use netstat I checked it out. I noticed connections where lingering but finally would go away. However, the problem still remains, after about the 100th connection, 5 second pause between connections. I get timeout errors. If I close the proram and restart it they go away. So for some reason I feel that the connections are leaving behind something. Netstat dosent show it. I've even tried adding the instances of the client to a list and each time one is finish remove it from the list and then set it to null. Is there a way to kill a port? Maybe that would work, if I killed the port the connection was being made on? Is it possible this is a Windows OS issue? Something thats used to prevent viruses? I'm making roughly a connection a minute and mainint that connection for about 1 minute before moving on to the next with atleast 20 concurent if not more connections at the same time. What dosent make sense to me is that shuting down the program seem sto clean up whatever resources I'm not cleaning up in my code. I'm using an class I found on the internet that allows socks5 proxies to be used with the socket class. So i'm really at a loss, any advice or direction to head woudl be great? It dosent have to be pretty. I'm have tempted to wite to a text file where I was in my connection list and shutdown the program and then have anohter program restart it to pick up where it left off at this point.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Sockets implement IDisposable. Only calling Dispose or Close will cause the socket to give give up the unmanaged resources in a deterministic manner. This is causing you to run out of the resources that the socket uses (probably a network handle of some sort), even though you may not any managed object useing them.

So you should probably just do

```
 socket.Shutdown(SocketShutdown.Both);
 socket.Close();
```

To be clear setting the socket to Null does not do this because setting the socket to null only causes the sockets to be placed on the freachable queue, to have its finalizer called when it gets around to processing the freachable queue.

You may want to review [this article](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/magazine/bb985010.aspx) which gives a good model on how Unmanaged resources are dealt with in .NET

**Update**
I checked and Sockets do indeed contain a handle to a [WSASocket](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms742212%28VS.85%29.aspx). So unless you call close or dispose you'll have to wait until the Finalizers run (or exiting the appplication) for you to get them back.

Comment: so how would you close or dispose of the sockets to make sure I can get them all back?

Comment: `socket.Close();` or `socket.Dispose();`. Note: if you do decide to keep `socket.Disconnect(true);` make sure do it before close or dispose because it will throw a `ObjectDisposedException` if you do it after. Also I didn't mention it earlier but you can also use the `using` keyword

Answer (score 1):

Sounds like your connections aren't really closed. Without seeing the code, it's hard to troubleshoot this; can you boil it down to a program that loops through an open-close sequence?

If the connection doesn't close as expected, you can probably see what state it is in with netstat. Do you have 200 established connections, or are they in some sort of closing state?

Comment: I checked netstat and its showing Time_Wait for connections I closed